# Is it possible to solve this or too many unknowns?

Tags: geometry

Here are what I know.

1. Length of $AB$ is known (and is variable)
2. Lines with arrows are parallel
3. $ A$ and $B$ are right angle to each other (not sure if this is the correct term)
4. Angle $A$ is known (and is variable)
5. $AC$ is the bisector of angle $ A$

What I need to find is $AC$

Is it possible to find a formula to get length of $AC$?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Vertical angles are equal and Alternate interior angles are equal. $$\sin\left(\dfrac{A}{2}\right)=\dfrac{AB}{AC}$$